# Difference between "import datetime" and "from datetime import datetime", which datetime to use

Tags: python, datetime

// Works and output is 2017-03-13 14:14:45.157593;
 then I can drill down to minute level, etc.

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.today())
```

// Works and output is 2017-03-13

```
import datetime
print(datetime.date.today())
```

// Both together It doesn't work. 
Outputs error: AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today'

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
print(datetime.today())
print(datetime.date.today())
```

1. Why there are two different modules?
2. Why I can't use them together? I don't want to use them together but need to understand, how the python interpreter is working (as it executes single statement at a time)... does it sees the first import and ignore the second import while executing the first statement or something else?

Thanks,
David

Comment: In python, the latest import of a module name overwrites all the other imports having the same name.

Comment: Outside of the specific question that has several answers, personally I choose a middle ground of `import datetime as dt` and then I don't have to keep typing `datetime.datetime` out when I want to use that specific functionality. `dt.date.today()` would also be viable in that case. I don't know whether `dt` is a convention as much as `np` or `pd` though as it is for `numpy` and `pandas` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple

```
from foo import foo  # makes the foo namespace available
import foo  # also makes the foo namespace available, but overwrites the previous one
```

It's the same as:

```
foo = 1
foo = 3
```

or

```
def foo():
    ...

def foo():
    ...
```

or as

```
Class Foo(...):
    ...

Class Foo(...):
    ...
```

Python reads from top to bottom, so everything that has the same name than something written or imported, overwrites the previously declared / imported ones.

Answer (score 9):

There is only one module: `datetime`, which contains a class `datetime`.

If you do `import datetime`  then `datetime` is the module and `datetime.datetime` is the class.

If you do `from datetime import datetime` then `datetime` is the class and you don't have a name for the module.

If you do both, then `datetime` is the last one executed, since the name `datetime` is reassigned by the additional `import` statement.

This confusion is why PEP 8 suggests different casing for module names and class names (the class should be named `DateTime` according to PEP 8) but `datetime` was in the standard library well before PEP 8 was written.

Answer (score 2):

1.) There are not 2 different modules. `import datetime` is importing datetime.py, which is the actual file that contains the `date` and `datetime` classes. If you do this, you import the whole file, whereas if you do `from datetime import datetime`, you are only importing the datetime class within that file.

2.) As @Apero stated, the import of datetime (the file) actually overrides your import of the class, which is why you then get the error. The interpreter basically ignores the line `from datetime import datetime` once you import it on a file level.